# Unable to install "GNU Image Manipulation program"

Tags: software-installation

I'm have been trying to install gimp from the ubuntu software center and I get the following error: Unable to install **" GNU image manipulation program": cannot perform the following tasks:**

How do I fix this?

Comment: Since you have not said what commands and steps you have done and we cant guess can not say. What are the exact steps and commands you have tried?

Comment: I'm trying to install it from the ubuntu software app

Comment: OK so you are using the Software Center what is the error message or what does it do. All this belongs in the question.

Comment: Okay, when it installs it goes 14% and goes back to 5% and return  the "cannot perform the following tasks": when I click on the error it doesn't show which tasks exactly

Comment: Open a terminal and enter the command `sudo apt install gimp`

Comment: Have you followed [this reference](https://linoxide.com/install-gimp-on-ubuntu/)? or any other reference or instruction? Please [edit] your question to include all the steps you have taken, don't assume we know what you have (or haven't) done. Don't add to the comment trail, [edit] your question!

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Thank you, installing it via the terminal it worked.

Comment: @ThandolwenkosiNdzimande I have written that as an answer. Please accept it if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue with the snap store, and cannot be addressed unless you provide more logs/screenshot.

Install GIMP from the terminal instead.

```
sudo apt install gimp
```